# How to alert user that input type text detects a dot when user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html and jquery code that alerts the user to have numbers only to input.
I want to alert the user when user inputs a dot '.' in the text field.

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="form-group" id="parentID">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID Number (10 max numbers)" id="childID" name="idnumber" type="text" maxlength="10"  required autofocus>
    <span id="checkID"></span>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var ID = $("#childID").val();

if (ID.indexOf(".") != -1) {
    $("#checkID").html("ID number must contain numbers only");
    $("#checkID").css("color", "orange");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#childID").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

//In this function it will disable special characters in user input but still accepts the '.' and '>' character type, what keycode is it to disable that 2 character?
$(function() {
    $('#parentID').on('keydown', '#childID', function(e) {-1 !== $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) || /65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode) && (!0 === e.ctrlKey || !0 === e.metaKey) || 35 <= e.keyCode && 40 >= e.keyCode || (e.shiftKey || 48 > e.keyCode || 57 < e.keyCode) && (96 > e.keyCode || 105 < e.keyCode) && e.preventDefault() });
})
</script>
</html>
```

I want the span id="checkID" to appear when the input field detects a dot on keyup. I tried using indexOf() but the span tag won't appear. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code in fiddle. Please find the updated code in below fiddle link. Just added one function and updated keyup and keypress events.

```
$(function() {
    $('#parentID').on('keypress keyup', '#childID', function(e) {
        if(isNumber(e)){
            $("#checkID").html("");
        } else{
            //e.preventDefault();
            $("#checkID").html("ID number must contain numbers only");
            $("#checkID").css("color", "orange");
        }
    });
});


function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode <= 46 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

See the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sreerajsaseendran/2dkb4dhv/5/)

It shows the error message. If you don't want to allow other characters please uncomment //e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#childID").keyup(function(){

    if ($("#childID").val().indexOf('.') > -1) {

     alert('dot');
     }


});
```

**[Working Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/2vjoh4xb/)**

**[Working Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/2vjoh4xb/1/)**

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano : great ! check out this demo too https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/2vjoh4xb/1/

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano : did you see my second demo ? alert remains if user continue typing with dot in it . Alert message always show in red. But the answer which you have accepted , in that alert message disappears if user continues typing with dot. did you really find that answer more correct ?

Answer (score 2):

try this this check it real time

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>

first name :<input type="text" name="firstname" class="tfield" id="myinput">


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myinput").on('change keyup keydown',function(){
  var thetext = $(this).val();
  if (thetext.indexOf('.') != -1) 
  {
   alert("contains dot sign")
  }
  else
  {
   //no need
  }
 });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write one javascript function which will check the charCode. The keyCode for dot is 46. so javascript function may like this

```
$('#childID').keypress(function (e) {
   //if the letter is dot
   if (e.which == 46) {
       //display alert error message
       alert("you cant enter dot");
       $(this).focus();
       return false;
   }
});
```

This will not let the user type dot in the text field.
Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>

Enter text :<input type="text" name="childID" id="childID">

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#childID').keypress(function (e) {
        //if the letter is dot
        if (e.which == 46) {
            //display alert error message
            alert("you cant enter dot");
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
  });
});


</script>
```